# What test/method is suited for analysing and modeling answers from a survey?

Tags: categorical-data, survey, interaction

People got a list of different documents and were asked if they find things important or not and if they think the documents would be easy to get or not.
People belong to different groups and have different professions.
For answering they had three choices:
0 = not important
2 = moderately important
4 = very important

and the same for easiness:
0 = not difficult
2 = moderately difficult
4 = very difficult
*no answer* was also possible, so there can be also missing values.

My question is:
How could the data be analysed with statistical methods to find out

- how profession and group influence what is important for the people? (= effect and interaction of those 2 variables on the "importance-value")
- and for which documents there are statistically significant differences what is important for them

Expected result (simple example): for a salesman the product data sheet is very important, someone working in service will need the documentation more often etc. and marketing people often need press releases.

What kind of test or analysis method would be appropriate to analyse this kind of data?

For sure, this is no designed experiment, so the number of people per group and per profession is not always the same.

I assume this is kind of a standard problem - where can I find a good tutorial for such kind of analysis?